# Proper way to create file of size "x" for use with mmap, ect

Tags: ios, c, posix

I need to create a file of precisely *x* bits (which will then be `mmap`'d).

I thought using `lseek()` or `ftruncate()` was sufficient, until I saw code from various sources (ex. [Mozilla](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/3d846420a907/xpcom/glue/FileUtils.cpp#l61)) using `fcntl()` with `F_PREALLOCATE` **first**, *then* used `ftruncate()`.

From the doc's, I can't ascertain why one would do this, and if it is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not necessary. If you use `ftruncate` it is possible that the file is *virtually* constructed, means that blocks are reserved in the total allocated blocks count but not really allocated to the file (files can have holes relatively to their allocated blocks). In that case, block allocation is deferred until read or write on it.

If you use `F_PREALLOCATE` then the allocation is not deferred.

I'm not sure this will makes any real difference; may be in time but I can't really see why. It may be a fragmentation concern.